# Переход по кнопке из одной страницы в другую Angular7

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-code

При нажатии на зеленую кнопку должна открыться другая страница
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

которую я создал в той же папке
вот расположение этих компонентов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот например: Нажимаю на кнопку метки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и открывается это окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы задаете идентичный вопрос уже в какой раз и предыдущие были закрыты, потому что вопрос непонятен

Comment: @overthesanity подскажите пожалуйста что именно не понятно, я не знаю что именно непонятно

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @overthesanity а так понятно?

Comment: @ИванСмирнов Нет, не понятно

Comment: @Жак-ивкусто ну я не знаю если и это не понятно, просто надо сделать банальный переход по кнопке на свою созданную страницу

Comment: @ИванСмирнов Прочтите про роутинг и навигацию в angular7. В данном случае непонятно с чем именно у вас проблема. Если вы уже пытались решить эту проблему и у вас не получилось, то опишите то, как вы ее решали. Если вы ничего не делали, а просто разместили кнопку на странице, то читайте про роутинг и навигацию.

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот почитайте про роутинг если вы хотите переход без перезагрузки всего сайта
https://metanit.com/web/angular2/7.1.php
а вот навигация
https://metanit.com/web/angular2/7.5.php
Для вас подходит навигация Это тот же Router только с методом navigate
надо определить в car.component.ts кнопку с помощью которой мы будем перенаправлять с одной страницы на другую

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'car',
    template: `<div>
                    <nav>
                        <a routerLink="">Главная</a>
                        <a routerLink="/about">О сайте</a>
                    </nav>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    <button (click)="goHome()">На главную</button>
               </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router){}
    goHome(){

        this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
}
```

В этом коде мы переходим по клику на кнопку на страницу about.component
Это если у вас только 1 компонент 
Если же их несколько то прописываете каждому свою кнопку и свой обработчик событий

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте основную информацию из текста по ссылкам в ответ. Так ответ не перестанет быть полезным если ссылки протухнут. В нынешнем виде ответ, к сожалению, следует преобразовать в комментарий, т.к. ответы-ссылки не разрешены.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а так пойдет? Для него вторая часть этой ссылки не нужна т.к у него всего лишь 1 компонент. Да, мой ответ был неполон, но все же настаиваю на то, что надо оставлять ссылки в ответах для будущих посетителей

Comment: Да, так нормально) Ссылки не запрещены и приветствуются, но ответ не может из одних только ссылок состоять, т.к. они протухнуть могут)